# Laravel image upload is too slow

Tags: php, laravel, image-resizing

I am using laravel intervention package for image resize. But it is very slow when posting the post with images in live server. I am using below code to process the image and upload. I am uploading 5 images at once. Can i use Javascripts to resize image before upload. I am not using JS for upload but i am using js for preview thumbnail image and delete button to remove it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TZVk.jpg)

this is is the form field

`<input value="{{old('image_01')}}" required name="image_01" type="file" class="custom-file-input " id="inputGroupFile01"> <label for="inputGroupFile01">Add a photo</label>`

```
$image01_name ='';
        if ($request->hasFile('image_01')){
            $image01 = $request->image_01;
            $img01 = Image::make($image01);
            $height = $img01->height();
            $width = $img01->width();
            if ($width > $height) {
                $im = $img01->resize(700, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                });
            }
            if ($width < $height) {
                $im = $img01->resize(null, 467, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                });
            }

            $image01_name = str_slug($request->title).'_'.mt_rand(1, 100).'-'.time().'_1.'.$image01->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $thumb01_name = str_slug($request->title).'_'.mt_rand(1, 100).'-'.time().'_1_t.'.$image01->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $img = Image::canvas(700,467);
            $img->insert($im, 'center');
            $img->insert( $waterMarkUrl , 'center-center', 10, 10);
            $img->save('storage/'.$image01_name);
            $thumb = $img01->fit(450,300);
            $thumb->save('storage/'.$thumb01_name);
```

Comment: Could you add some code showing how you're uploading your images? - if with ajax type or similar flavour of request, I can assist in coming up with a js based solution

Comment: this is is the form field

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question, without a little more from you, I'm unable to help

Comment: You need to determine what makes us a slow process. The uploading? The resizing? Why perform resizing immediately, your can use queued jobs, that's what they are meant for. Also, how much CPU power does your server have?